# Java - Inline definition of comparator for Collection.max

Tags: java

I am looking for a Java equivalent for python snippet

```
max_valued_key = max(str_to_double_map.keys(), key=lambda x: str_to_double_map[x])
```

I want to something standard like Collections.max
Is there a way to do this with *inline definition of Comparator* since I don't want to write one more class for every other comparator.

I tried following code unsuccessfully

```
depScores = foo();
String dep = Collections.max(depScores.keySet(), new Comparator<String>() {
  @Override
  public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
    return depScores.get(o1).compareTo(depScores.get(o2));
  }
});
```

depScores variable is not readable from comparator.
Looks like in java inner class cannot access non-final variable from outside!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just declare `depScores` as a final variable.  If for some reason you can't, create a second (final) variable that points to it.

Local classes can capture variables only if they are final.

---

As a (very) late addendum, it is trivial to create a custom `Comparator` from a lambda in Java 8:

```
String dep = Collections.max(
    depScores.keySet(),
    Comparator.comparing(k -> depScores.get(k))
);
```

You can get even more terse by replacing the lambda `k -> depScores.get(k)` with the method reference `depScores::get`.

The rules for capturing local variables like `depScore` are a little more flexible for lambdas than inner classes: captured variables need only be *effectively final*.  In other words, they must be assigned exactly once, though they needn't be explicitly marked `final`.

Answer (score 4):

What you want is (will be) possible with Java 8:

```
Map<String,Double> map…
String maxKey=Collections.max(map.keySet(), (x,y)->Double.compare(map.get(x),map.get(y)));
```

or even shorter

```
String maxKey = Collections.max(map.keySet(), Comparator.comparingDouble(map::get));
```

---

For previous Java version you have to use:

```
String maxKey=Collections.max(map.keySet(), new Comparator<String>(){
    public int compare(String x, String y) {
        return Double.compare(map.get(x),map.get(y));
    }
});
```

Problems with `map` not being `final` can be circumvented by assigning it to a final variable right before the invocation:

```
final Map<String,Double> fmap=map;
String maxKey=Collections.max(map.keySet(), new Comparator<String>(){
    public int compare(String x, String y) {
        return Double.compare(fmap.get(x),fmap.get(y));
    }
});
```

---

But I think even more straightforward and more efficient will be the following helper method as it does not require any hash lookups:

```
static <K,V extends Comparable<V>> K keyForHighestValue(Map<K,V> map) {
    V maxValue=Collections.max(map.values());
    for(Map.Entry<K,V> e:map.entrySet()) {
        if(e.getValue()==maxValue) return e.getKey();
    }
    throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
}
```