# Is there any particular use of closure in swift? and what's the benefit?

Tags: swift, closures

I have learnt Swift for a  while and I have read the Swift language guide.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID94

The concept closure is new to me. I think I can understand how to use it, but where I can use it? what is the benefit of it?

I googled and get the answer [When to use closures in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29824488/when-to-use-closures-in-swift)

I do not thinks the answer is satisfying. The language guide writes so much about it, I guess it is a very important feature of the language, and maybe it's widely used in the framework.

Could anyone show me more example to show it's power? 
Thanks a lot.

Comment: It is used almost anywhere. Thats why almost any language has them now.

Comment: I am new to swift, I have used java for years and never got a chance to use closures ( Java 8 added it )

Comment: You probably did. Closures (or something similar) were always in Java, only with a terrible syntax. Since there was no way to write an individual function, you had to wrap it in an interface and create a class for it. `Comparator` interface is a prime example. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/19785549/669586, that `new Comparator<String>() { ...` is a way to create an unnamed function to compare strings. Real closures just remove the unnecessary class around it.

Comment: Even the new Java syntax is still pretty terrible though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question might be a little broad, but I will try to recap.

Referring to the [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html):

> Closures are self-contained blocks of functionality that can be passed
>   around and used in your code.

You should use closure(s) when you want to pass a chunk of code as a parameter to a method that you want to execute it asynchronously.

To make it simpler -by giving a real-world example-, imagine that there is a method responsible for scanning the user's photos, so the method should returns an array of photos and another array of videos:

*Pesudo-code:*

```
// the method should scan the the user's photos and return them after fetching is finished

// the 'completion' (success) closure should returns two arrays
// what if there is something wrong happened? another closure should returns an error

// for the example purposes they are arrays of strings, the error is also a string
func scanPhotos( completion: @escaping (_ photos: [String], _ videos: [String]) -> (), failure: @escaping (String) -> ()) {
    // imagine that the scanning has been successfully done and you filled the two arrays:

    //if scanningSuccess {
        let fetchedPhotos = [String]()
        let fetchedVideos = [String]()

        completion(fetchedPhotos, fetchedVideos)
    //} else {
        // if something goes wrong
        failure("the error!!")
    //}
}
```

Calling the method:

```
scanPhotos(completion: { (photos, videos) in
    // now you can use the fetched photos and videos
}, failure: { error in
    // display an alert -for example- based on the error is saying...
})
```

Note the the scanning proccess should be executed asynchronously, when it finished, one of the two blocks (success or failure) should be executed.

---

**Some of the popular methods that work with clousres**:

- [animateWithDuration:animations:completion:](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622515-animatewithduration)
- [urlSession(_:dataTask:didReceive:completionHandler:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/urlsessiondatadelegate/1410027-urlsession)
- [sort(by:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array/2296801-sort)

**AGAIN**: it is just a simple usage of the closures; You need to check the documentation for more details.

I hope it helped.

Comment: Thank you！  It helps a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Closures are a concept you use mainly on asynchronous function calls. (at least I do so)

A good example where Apple uses closures is `URLSession`:

```
func downloadTask(with url: URL, completionHandler: @escaping (URL?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void) -> URLSessionDownloadTask
```

This method creates an `URLSessionDownloadTask` that runs in a background thread. When you call this method, you are passing a closure as `completionHandler`. This closure is executed, when the task has finished.

---

There are some other cases, but I haven't used them this much yet, because I love the delegate pattern. I found an [article](https://medium.cobeisfresh.com/why-you-shouldn-t-use-delegates-in-swift-7ef808a7f16b#.g62vffgev) that compares Closures and Delegates in Swift.

Delegates in Swift have a big problem: Unless you are using `@objc`, you have to implement **every** method of a `protocol`, which could lead to lots of unnecessary code and would look confusing. That's why I guess it would be much better to use closures in many cases.