# return value in function handler with swift 3

Tags: swift, closures, completionhandler

I want to write a swift 3 function which reads exif data from a photo (PHAsset). I am working with requestImageData call. This call does not seems to be synchronous, even if I set `isSynchronous` option to `true`.

What I want to do is to return a value from the handler block. This code does not work because my return isn't in the function body. This return is in the handler.

How should I do to make this function synchronous and to return the properties dictionary?

```
func read_exif(photo:PHAsset) -> [String:Any] {
    let manager = PHImageManager.default()
    let options = PHImageRequestOptions()
    options.isSynchronous = true
    manager.requestImageData(for: photo, options: options) { (result, string, orientation, info) -> Void in
        let img:CIImage = CIImage(data:result!)!
        return img.properties
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40714488/is-there-any-particular-use-of-closure-in-swift-and-whats-the-benefit/40715084#40715084), hope it will be -somehow- useful to you.

Comment: use completion handler for such issue

Comment: I am sorry but those answers does not respond to my initial question. What i want to do is to make my read_exif function blocking and waiting until the result is returned...